# Prove $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty}-\cos(\pi\sqrt{4n^2+10})$ exists and is equal to $-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

My idea is to take two subsequence converging to different limits. On this step I have problem. How can I set equation  of subsequence when $\cos$ has certain value and $n \to \infty$?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}-\cos(\pi\sqrt{4n^2+10})
$$
If I say that $\frac{5}{4n^2} \to 0$ than $n \to \infty$, I have $\lim_{n \to \infty}-\cos(2\pi n) = -1$. Is this right?

Comment: I am not so sure exactly what you mean with two subsquences. The cosine is periodic and the square root term goes to infinity. So the cosine keeps on producing values between -1 and 1

Comment: @imranfat What do you mean? If this is a sketch of argument towards the proof, then it fails: $\sqrt{4n^2}$ would also go to infinity, but $\cos \pi\sqrt{4n^2}$ does have a limit.

Comment: If the limit of a sequence exists, then every subsequence must converge to the same limiting value. Therefore, if you can find two subsequences that converge to different values the limit does not exist.

Comment: I didn't catch that pi...

Comment: @ClementC. What is that limit than? As far as I know, $n$ does not have to be only integers...Putting it in my graphing calculator, it still keeps oscillating

Comment: If $n$ is an integer (it's a sequence), then it has limit one. If the limit is taken for the function on a real variable, not for the sequence ($n$ can be any real number), then there is no limit... but by convention, using $n$ and "sequence" in the OP's question strongly suggests the former interpretation should prevail, IMO.

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, as a sequence, that makes sense. Cleared up now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

The cosine is continuous and $$\pi\sqrt{4n^2+10}= 2\pi n\left(1+\frac5{4n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Can you explain why this is so?

Comment: @Dr. MV glancing at it, I wanted to clarify: this implies the limit actually exists (and is 1), doesn't it?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes.  The limit is $1$.

Comment: Nice approach. Wondering if there would be any other approach to deal with something like this.

Comment: @Denis Sure.  Just use the [Binomial Series Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) or equivalently, the Taylor Series for $\sqrt{1+10/n^2}$.

Comment: @Shailesh Thank you;  very appreciative.  As for other approaches, there might be a slick of showing this.

Comment: @ClementC.  Nice catch.  I did this on my "not-so-smart" phone.  And it is actually $5/4$ since there is a factor of $1/2$ that comes from the binomial expansion.  That is $\left(1+x \right)^{1/2}=1+\frac12 x+O(x^2)$.  Here, as you pointed out, $x=10/(4n^2)$ and so $10/8n^2=5/(4n^2)$.  +1 for your comment!!

Comment: @clementc. Oh, right again.  Edited and another +1

Answer (score 2):

HINT:
Let
$$
a_n=\sqrt{4n^2+10}-2n={10\over\sqrt{4n^2+10}+2n}.
$$
It is clear that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, and:
$$
\cos(\pi\sqrt{4n^2+10})=\cos(2n\pi+\pi a_n)=\cos(\pi a_n).
$$

Comment: Very, very good!

Comment: @Aretino. What if $n$ is fractional?

Comment: I presume this is the limit of a sequence, not of a function. If $n\in \mathbb{R}$ the limit doesn't obviously exist.

Comment: @imranfat $n$ is integer number by condition

Comment: @Denis Yes, that makes sense to me now...(Actually a great problem)

Answer (score 0):

One may also argue that $$\cos(\pi\sqrt {4n^2+10})=\cos(\pi\sqrt {4n^2+10}-2\pi n)  = \cos\left(\pi\frac{(\sqrt {4n^2+10})^2-4n^2}{\sqrt {4n^2+10}+2n}\right)  = \cos\left(\pi\frac{10}{\sqrt {4n^2+10}+2n}\right).$$

Clearly, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{10}{\sqrt {4n^2+10}+2n}=0$, hence, by continuity,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(\pi\sqrt {4n^2+10})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos\left(\pi\frac{10}{\sqrt {4n^2+10}+2n}\right)=\cos 0=1. $$